# Html.BeginForm with specified arguments uses GET instead of POST

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm creating a form with .NET MVC and when I pass arguments in @BeginForm, it uses get no matter what I do.

This is what I have so far:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("QueryIndexUpdate", "Analysis", FormMethod.Post)){}
```

I've tried removing ", FormMethod.Post" to see what would happen, and still uses GET.
When I use BeginForm() with not arguments, it uses POST, but calls the wrong method in the controller (it goes back to index).

Any ideas why I might have this issue?

Controller

```
[Route("query/_queryindexfilterpartial")] 
[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken] 
public ActionResult QueryIndexUpdate(QueryFilterViewModel filterModel) 
{ 
    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
    { 
        filterModel.Field = filterModel.Field ?? 0; filterModel.Item = ListBoxExtension.GetSelectedValues<int>("Item"); 
    } 

    return RedirectToAction("Query", "Analysis", filterModel); 
}
```

Comment: What does the controller action look like?

Comment: `[Route("query/_queryindexfilterpartial")]
        [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult QueryIndexUpdate(QueryFilterViewModel filterModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                filterModel.Field = filterModel.Field ?? 0;
                filterModel.Item= ListBoxExtension.GetSelectedValues<int>("Item");
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Query", "Analysis", filterModel);
        }`

Comment: Should've put it in the question. I've done it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the controller method. I can see that the name of it isn't matching to the form. That could be why it's never reaching it.

Comment: It actually is, I removed the prefix just to make it simple here. Also updated the controller code in the question.

Comment: Is the model in the view where the form is located ''QueryFilterViewModel "?

Comment: Yes. Again, it works absolutely fine if I remove the arguments from BeginForm and get the model from the index using that same name.

I just can't seem to make the form post instead of get whenever I have arguments in it :/

Comment: @Erik And there's not another method in the controller with the same name?

Comment: No, that's the only one.

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest from looking at the code given is to remove the route.

Comment: Just tried that (and I'll keep the method without a route actually, because I don't need it). But it didn't work. My URL got populated with a lot of get parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was having was not because of BeginForm.
BeginForm worked fine and posted everything, but RedirectToAction only passes parameters as GET, therefore change it to something else and it all works as expected.

Comment: But that's the response from the server not the form post request to the server.  It's not possible for a response to dictate what your request was.  It happens after, sequentially.